# AJAX call not updating page - Ajax pagination and layered navigation extension

Tags: url, ajax

I have just adopted Magento and have to say I am very impressed. However as I am a noob I am having a couple of issues, so I would appreciate some advice/help

I am trying to implement a module called ajax pagination and layered navigation onto our site however the ajax update seems to be failing somewhere.

http://thealpacacentre.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=alpaca

We're having to force a browser refresh on the page after applying the layered navigation filters on the left for the page to be correctly rendered.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: check your request and response of that ajax call. When I check I got this error

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://thealpacacentre.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/pager-anim.gif"

Comment: Hi Keyul, thankyou for your reply. I have found and replaced the image but it still doesn't seem to be processing.

Comment: Please provide the full name or a link of the extension you use.

Comment: Looks like this is working as intended now. Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we managed to fix the Ajax extension by altering the css in our custom theme.

The extension we were using (ajax layered navigation pagination pro ) was deleting the div class causing the page to format incorrectly.

We added a new div class in the left.phtml file in our custom theme.

So after

```
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
```

insert another div class. I used

```
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
```

then before

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

insert a closing div

```
<div>
```

Also make sure that you alter the file /skin/frontend/base/default/js/vpager.js to the correct div classes if using a custom theme. Ours didn't so we had to alter and swap some code to our div classes.